# Jquery HTML Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I'm using JQuery to work on a project and am having some trouble with the html() method. Is there any way that the method can ignore certain tags in the text? For example if the string is

```
"A paragraph can be started with a <code><p><code> tag"
```

How can I make it so that the code tag will be interpreted but the p tag with it's brackets will not? If the solution requires something beside Jquery, still let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Would it be like 'A paragraph can be started with a <code><pre><p></pre><code> tag

Comment: @HendryTanaka add an answer instead of a comment. I'll vote it up

Comment: Use mine. It's working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Use symbol `&lt;` and `&lt;/ &gt;` for closing tag like this.
Example :
"A paragraph can be started with a <p> Tutorial </p> tag"

`&lt;` is `<` , `&gr;` is `>`. Combining both of them will create a bracket as tag that will not interpreted by browser as a html tag.

Bonus: [DEMO](http://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/tags-page.php). Easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
"A paragraph can be started with a <code><p>...</p></code> tag"
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this but not sure if support all browsers.
 [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbsuab3s/)

```
A paragraph can be started with a <xmp> <p> </xmp> tag
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you havent enclosed your code tag `'</code>'`

If you are trying to print html in plain text try and enclose the words in `<xmp> </xmp>` tags instead

Your Case:

```
"A paragraph can be started with a <xmp> <p> </xmp> tag"
```

or even:

```
<xmp>A paragraph can be started with a <p> tag</xmp>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I found using jquery functions. :)

```
<script>    
 $( "div" ).html("A paragraph can be started with a <code>" );
 $( "div" ).append( $("<code>").text("<p>"));
 $( "div" ).append("<code> tag.");  
</script>
```