# update text on a textarea as user types, based on the syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

For example I have a textarea and I'm typing this:

```
<b>Bolded</b> and <i>italic</i> and <b><i>bold+italic</i></b>
```

as I am typing this to my textarea, the text will become bolded or italic like this:

> **Bolded** and *italic* and ***bold+italic***

Note that it does not have to be `<b>` or `<i>`, it could be `**text**` and it becomes **text**, I have no problem on creating the custom syntax, I just need to know if it is possible to update it live in `js` or `jquery`?

I was thinking of using (this is in CoffeeScript):

```
$('div#mdEditor').on 'change', ->
 # but no idea how to continue?
```

**UPDATE**

It does not have to be `textarea` though, I am using a contenteditable `div` so I can parse it on live if needed, again, I have no idea how.

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351435/jquery-html-method/26351502#26351502)?

Comment: Nope, I need it parsed AS i typed, yours need a page refresh

Comment: type? than you do not need `$('div #mdEditor').onchange()` event but `<input>` on `keydown` event, right?

Comment: Why don't you use [markdown](http://epiceditor.com/) editor instead?

Comment: @Rahil: since I need it customized

Comment: @HendryTanaka: Is that going to be overkill?

Comment: @user2002495 If you want to customize then probably YES!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/

```
Goal: When we paste content in editor allow only <p>, <b>, <a>, and <i> tags only
```